# Aren't we summing extra area in this question

Tags: integration, iterated-integrals

This question is rather a simple change of parameters in double integrals, that I am having problem understanding why is it correct.

> Let $D=\left\{{(x,y)}, ~1\le x^2+y^2\le 4 ~ , x^2+y^2\le2x\right\}$,
>   Find the area of $D$.

Now, the question is the same as saying find $\iint_D1dxdy$, considering polar representation $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta, J=r$, it's the same as finding $\iint_{D'}rdrd\theta$

Now, the question is, why am I not summing to much area.

$D'=\left\{(r,\theta) | 1<r<2\cos\theta, \theta\in\frac{1}{3}[-\pi,\pi] \right\}$ according the solution.

Now, it didn't make sense where the $\theta$ came from, so I plotted the area in wolframalpha.

Here is what the area looks like

[image: the picture of the area]

Looking at the $D'$, it's calculating the arcs in the green, but not the red, the question is; **where does the red goes?**

I understand that manipulating the equation gets you the right formula, for example:

$1 \le x^2+y^2 \le 4 \Rightarrow 1 \le r^2 \le 4$

$x^2+y^2 \le 2x \Rightarrow r^2 \le 2r\cos\theta \Rightarrow r \le 2\cos\theta$

But then again, **how do we find the $\theta$?**

Comment: Angle $\pi/3$ is not the same as writing $y = \pi/3 x$. Is angle $1$ given by $y=x$? No, this is angle $\pi/4$.

Comment: The angle according to the question is $\pi/3$, looking at it, yes; it's not right, the angle should be the intersection of the two small circles (based at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red parts *are* included in $D'$ as the angles of $\pm\tfrac{\pi}{3}$ do not correspond to the (straight) lines you drew, but to the points of intersection between the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$.

> But then again, **how do we find the $\theta$?**

To find this angle, look for the points of intersection:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x^2+y^2=1\\x^2+y^2=2x\end{array}\right. \implies 2x=1$$
Now $x=r\cos\theta$ in polar coordinates and on the unit circle, $r=1$; so:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \implies \theta = \pm\frac{\pi}{3}$$